# approximation of differential equation through chebyshev differentiation matrices

Tags: numerical-methods

All,

i'm trying to solve a linear differential equation, through discretizing the domain into the chebyshev grid and using spectral method ( approximating first and second derivative with differentiation matrices- polynomial approximation),and finding eigenvalue of matrices,   as far as i know this have to have same answer of root of characteristics , but in practice eigenvalue and root are not match? where i move / think wrongly?

Comment: To provide more detail , here is the Deferential equation : A∇^2.∇^2 φ+ B∇^2 φ+Cφ=0    , The Laplacian ( ∇^2)  will be replaced by approximated chebyshev differentiation matrices